# How to perform login field for login.microsoftonline.com using Jmeter

Tags: authentication, cookies, jmeter

I need to perform one app that is signed in via login.microsoftonline.com, but I get this error "We can`t sign you in your browser is currently set to block cookies. you need to allow cookies to use this service." maybe someone else has experienced something similar.

I tried changing HTTP Cookie Manager type from standart to others, also I used CookieManager.save.cookies with true and false but nothing worked.

[HTTP Cookie Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kBIr.png)

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdEUY.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygSkN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to have the request to `login.microsoftonline.com` as the very first request in your JMeter script.

My expectation is that you're trying to test an application which uses [Microsoft Identity Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) as authentication provider so depending on your application auth flow you need to pass some parameters to this `login.microsoftonline.com` page and the parameters need to be [extracted from the previous request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/).

So try starting with your application login page and I believe you should be [redirected](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) to the `login.microsoftonline.com` with valid cookies and appropriate parameters